# AB+C when you only have ABC and C

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate `AB+C` (`A`, `B` and `C` being boolean values) but I only have the values `ABC` and `C`. I can negate, OR, and AND to my heart's content, but I am only getting `ABC` and `C` out of the system.

Specifically there is a service that has two boolean state variables. One is a combination of three internal properties and is only true when all three are true, but one of the three state properties is also available. I'm just trying to figure out if I can calculate the value I want without asking for them to add `A` and `B` as separate values.

`AB` is `A and B`

`A + B` is `A or B`

Comment: by `AB` you mean `A AND B` I suppose?

Comment: Yes, `AB` means `A AND B`.

Comment: and `AB+C` I assume means `(A AND B) OR C` because AND has higher precedence. Is that what you mean?

Comment: This sounds more like logic than linear algebra. Also, it is not a programming related question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to get the value I want AB+C without having A and B separately. I was hoping to get what I needed from just doing the math without having to go to the service provider and ask for them to pull out A and B as separate properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can compute `AB+C` in any case knowing only the value of `C` and `ABC`:

- If `C` is true, `AB+C` is true
- If `C` is false, `ABC` is false and you can't find out anything about `AB`.

**Old Answer** - which is wrong as stated in the comments:

I'll give it a try. You can construct `not(not(ABC)+C)+C`:

```
not(not(ABC)+C)+C = not(not(A)+not(B)+not(C)+C))+C
                  = not(not(A)+not(B))+C
                  = AB+C
```

Comment: `not(not(ABC)+C)` is false. because `not(C)+C` is true

Comment: Props for making the question actually clear though.

Comment: You are right, I'll have to rethink my approach, thanks..

Comment: I like the edit you made.  You showed that it isn't possible. +1.